# Weighted correlation coefficient with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, pearson-correlation

Is there any way to compute weighted correlation coefficient with pandas? I saw that R has such a method.
Also, I'd like to get the p value of the correlation. This I did not find also in R.
Link to Wikipedia for explanation about weighted correlation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Weighted_correlation_coefficient

Answer (score 29):

I don't know of any Python packages that implement this, but it should be fairly straightforward to roll your own implementation.  Using the naming conventions of the wikipedia article:

```
def m(x, w):
    """Weighted Mean"""
    return np.sum(x * w) / np.sum(w)

def cov(x, y, w):
    """Weighted Covariance"""
    return np.sum(w * (x - m(x, w)) * (y - m(y, w))) / np.sum(w)

def corr(x, y, w):
    """Weighted Correlation"""
    return cov(x, y, w) / np.sqrt(cov(x, x, w) * cov(y, y, w))
```

I tried to make the functions above match the formulas in the wikipedia as closely as possible, but there are some potential simplifications and performance improvements.  For example, as pointed out by @Alberto Garcia-Raboso, `m(x, w)` is really just `np.average(x, weights=w)`, so there's no need to actually write a function for it.

The functions are pretty bare-bones, just doing the calculations.  You may want to consider forcing inputs to be arrays prior to doing the calculations, i.e. `x = np.asarray(x)`, as these functions will not work if lists are passed.  Additional checks to verify all inputs have equal length, non-null values, etc. could also be implemented.

Example usage:

```
# Initialize a DataFrame.
np.random.seed([3,1415])
n = 10**6
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.choice(3, size=n),
    'y': np.random.choice(4, size=n),
    'w': np.random.random(size=n)
    })

# Compute the correlation.
r = corr(df['x'], df['y'], df['w'])
```

There's a discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/94569) regarding the p-value.  It doesn't look like there's a generic calculation, and it depends on how you're actually getting the weights.

Comment: `np.average` admits a `weights` argument, so that you can define `m(x, w)` as `np.average(x, weights=w)` and so on.

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso: Thanks, I've added a remark regarding that.  For consistency, I left my code as is so that it matches the formulas in the linked wikipedia article as closely as possible.

Comment: Just in case somebody actually uses it, you can also change the definition of `cov(x, y, w)` to `return np.average((x - m(x, w)) * (y - m(y, w)), weights=w)`.

Comment: @RoobieNuby Why would you use np.average not change the other `m(*, *)` to use np.average

Comment: @DjangoTango My comment used the word *also*. So, after using Alberto Garcia-Raboso's definition for `m(x, w)`, you could then also define covariance using the same builtin function. In fact you could define `cov(x, y, w)` to be `m((x - m(x, w)) * (y- m(y, w)), w)`.

Answer (score 7):

The [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org) package has an [implementation of weighted correlation](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.corrcoef.html#statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.corrcoef).

Comment: This works, but the annoying thing I found is that statmodels does not want to give the correlation if there are nan values. So,  first I had to get rid of all nan values. also when I am passing an array and only certaion columns have nan I want the rest of columns' correlation to include the rows that other columns have with nan. But I guess  that is not possible. Maybe I need to substitute the NaN with the average. and then it will work

Comment: yes, nans are annoying and tend to propagate! But that makes sense really: leaves it up to you to decide what to do with them. Your approach sounds reasonable I suppose, though it'll reduce the correlations a bit. If there's not many, it won't make much difference though.