# Correlation between a column and a group of others in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in Data Science and Python, and learning Statistics at the same time as leasure. I am not a Computer Scientist , so sorry if this question may sounds basic.

I have a Dataframe, which I process using Pandas using Python 3. From a preliminary exploration, I suspect that one of the columns is correlated to the behavior of two others instead of just one.

I can calculate the correlation coefficient between two single columns. However, is there a way to calculate some sort of "weighted" correlation between one column and ***two*** others?

Comment: The r tag was suggested by SO. I kept it because R users might find the question useful because of the statistical part of this question. But you are right, perhaps it makes the question too ambiguous so I have approved your Edit suggestion, and removed the R tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weighted correlation coefficient with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641691/weighted-correlation-coefficient-with-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can compute and plot Correlation Matrix. Please refer http://www.marketcalls.in/python/quick-start-guide-compute-correlation-matrix-using-nsepy-pandas-python.html and [python documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html).