# SAS Proc Corr with Weighting in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation

I have a SAS script that uses the "[proc corr](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/66703/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_corr_syntax01.htm#procstat.corr.covopt)" procedure, along with [weighting](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Tips:Weighting_in_PROC_CORR) in order to create a weighted correlation matrix. I am now trying to reproduce this function in python, but I haven't found a good way of including the weighting in the output matrix.

While looking for a solution, I've found a few scripts and functions that calculate weighted correlation coefficients for two columns/variables ([examples](https://github.com/djburks/WPCC) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641691/weighted-correlation-coefficient-with-pandas)) using a weights array, but I am trying to create a weighted correlation matrix with many more variables. I've tried using these functions by looping through variable combinations, but it is running magnitudes slower than the SAS procedure.

I was wondering if there was an efficient way to create a weighted correlation matrix in python that works similarly to the SAS code, or at least returns equivalent results without looping through all variable combinations.

Comment: `numpy.cov` takes a weights parameter, try that? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html#numpy.cov

Comment: Doesn't that return covariance though? Or is there an easy way to go from covariance to correlation (like scaling the covariance results)? I'm newer on the stat side so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy's covariance takes two different kind of weights parameters - I don't have SAS to check against, but it is likely a similar approach.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html#numpy.cov

Once you have a covariance matrix, it can be converted to a correlation matrix using a formula like this

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Correlation_matrix

Complete example

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1., 1.1, 1.2, 0.9])

y = np.array([2., 2.05, 2.02, 2.8])

np.cov(x, y)
Out[49]: 
array([[ 0.01666667, -0.03816667],
       [-0.03816667,  0.151225  ]])

cov = np.cov(x, y, fweights=[10, 1, 1, 1])

cov
Out[51]: 
array([[ 0.00474359, -0.00703205],
       [-0.00703205,  0.04872308]])

def cov_to_corr(cov):
    """ based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Correlation_matrix """
    D = np.sqrt(np.diag(np.diag(cov)))
    Dinv = np.linalg.inv(D)
    return Dinv @ cov @ Dinv # requires python3.5, use np.dot otherwise

cov_to_corr(cov)
Out[53]: 
array([[ 1.        , -0.46255259],
       [-0.46255259,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: So if I have an n x m array with m different columns, and I wish to create a weighted correlation matrix for correlation between each two variables, I should loop through column pairs using your code example? I've tried similar implementation in the past, but the it took magnitudes longer than the SAS corr procedure. 

Edit: I'll try using np.cov with a single array as an input to get a weighted covariance matrix, then apply the cov_to_corr function.

Comment: No need to loop, `np.cov` also accepts single-argument matrix, see the linked docstring.