# weighted correlation in python

Tags: python, correlation, bayesian, weighted-average

I am trying to using the weighted correlation function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641691/weighted-correlation-coefficient-with-pandas)

```
def m(x, w):
    """Weighted Mean"""
    return np.sum(x * w) / np.sum(w)

def cov(x, y, w):
    """Weighted Covariance"""
    return np.sum(w * (x - m(x, w)) * (y - m(y, w))) / np.sum(w)

def corr(x, y, w):
    """Weighted Correlation"""
    return cov(x, y, w) / np.sqrt(cov(x, x, w) * cov(y, y, w))
```

This is the data that I am using

```
x = np.arange(78)
y = np.arange(21)
w = np.random.random((21,78)) # this is just an example matrix

# the key is to have a weight matrix that is of size (y.shape, x.shape)
```

Now when I try to compute the weighted correlation, I run into a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes`. Any suggestion on how can I modify the script to make it work for a dataset like this?

For reference, I am trying to implement the methods mentioned here in the heading `Bayesian Replay Analysis`  http://www.buzsakilab.com/content/PDFs/Grosmark2016Supp.pdf

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia link presented in the post you mention (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Weighted_correlation_coefficient), the size of the vectors `x` and `y` should be the same.